# XCUI testing, how to scroll to an element that is off screen in Xcode 7.1 Beta 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, automation

I'm attempting to automate a test that includes accessing an element that is initially off screen. I've tried the swipedown() method, among other things, and haven't been able to find a solution. I've seen posts saying that it should scroll down to an element when you attempt to tap it, but this is not working for me at the moment.

Comment: Yep, I've found this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16810, looks like it's broken currently and was looking for a work around.

Comment: It is not broken and accessible from my end. @AlexSchade

Answer (score 0):

I can show Center Control by :

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];

XCUICoordinate *from = [app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.99)];
XCUICoordinate *to = [app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.25)];
[from pressForDuration:0 thenDragToCoordinate:to];
```

you could try it.